# What is the best way to handle emails when using Rails + Devise for an API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise

I have a Rails-based API that has successfully integrated Devise. One remaining question I have is how to handle emails (confirmation and reset password). Devise automatically sends out these emails with links to its views. Since the API shouldn't handle views, what's the best way to deal with this? My questions are:

1. Is it inevitable that the API would contain some html templates since Devise sends out these emails? Is there a way for these templates to be on the client side?
2. How do I do with the links, which contains information like confirmation tokens and reset_password_tokens? I am not well-versed in client-side tech but should the links point to the client side's domain so that it can capture, rip out the tokens and make the calls in the background?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used Devise for a few API-only Rails projects. Frankly, IMHO, Devise is too heavy an opinionated for such projects. I *love* devise, but there's a lot of magic and assumptions. One of the assumptions is that you'll be using traditional Rails views. This isn't what you asked, but FWIW you might check out some other authentication libraries, like https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance.

1) I don't see a way for your client app to have an email template. This action is happening entirely outside your client. Rails is sending emails, which your users then view using their email client (I'm assuming your client app isn't actually an email client).

I think the Rails api is the proper place for email templates in this case. I cannot think of a way that you could involve your client app in this. Even if you could, why would you want to do so?

2) There are a few ways to handle the links to password resets. The first thing you could do, as you state, is simply to grab the data and write your own views. But that seems like quite a lot of work, and you might end up fighting a lot with Devise.

An easy solution is to just let Devise own this stuff, and use Rails views. It's messy, but simple and easy. Devise is very opinionated, and this is the path of least resistance. It seems to me that you are trying to swim upstream here, based on a principle of separation of concerns. I'd argue that using Devise makes it very difficult to do that.

If you really must have your client app render all views, including ones for this feature, then you might consider just rolling your own password reset feature and keeping Devise out of the mix.

Comment: thanks. I think I will leave these views in Devise for now and figure it out once I get to the client side. I think with Devise working nicely in JSON, the views are separated from the logic so it might not be as much fighting against Devise as I have done in the API.